# Jane Kelly: sharpshooter?

Tags: xcom-2

I just started a new XCom 2 game after a few months away. After completing the tutorial mission, Jane levelled up to the Sharpshooter class, instead of Ranger like she's always done. Is this a new feature introduced by a patch?

Edit: As said, this is the tutorial mission where Central and Jane show up, and the two rookies get killed. The game is fully patched up, plus I have the following mods enabled:

- Long War Perk Pack
- Full character customization from start
- All soldiers gain XP
- Chooseable AWC perks
- Larger starting squad

There are others, but those are the ones that I think should affect the character classes. This is also a clean install on a new PC, so the character pool is empty.

Comment: A few questions which might help people provide good answers: 1. Do you have any mods installed? 2. Have you added Jane Kelly to your "character pool"? 3. When you say "tutorial mission", are you definitely referring to the one where you rescue the Commander from the tube, and not "Operation Gatecrasher", which is the standard first mission with tutorial off?

Comment: If you want her to be a Ranger, you can force her to be one through the mod [Commander's Choice](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=688405905). It allows you to change the class of any squaddie to any other class.

Comment: Was she the first to be promoted? From my non-tutorial playing experience I think the first promotion is always a ranger. If your mods gave you more people in the tutorial, that might have changed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to a mod.

I've reviewed all the patch notes since launch, and there's no mention of any changes to Jane Kelly or the tutorial process.

I've also used my unmodded, fully patched game to test multiple run-throughs of the tutorial on different difficulty levels and Jane Kelly has remained true to her Ranger roots each time. I don't have any of the DLC installed though, so this test isn't as definitive as I'd like it to be.

Most of Jane Kelly's predetermined attributes are set in DefaultGameData.ini, but as far as I can tell there's nothing in *any* of the ini files that sets Jane's promotion class.

It's probably built into the tutorial code, but I can't view those details without the modding SDK installed. If it's not in the tutorial files the other likely location would be the code and data that handles the armory screens. From the mods you listed that probably makes Long War Perk Pack and Chooseable AWC Perks the main suspects.

Randomising Jane feels in keeping with the "style" of the Long War folks to me, so that would be my first guess, even though their changes notes don't seem to mention it anywhere I could find.

Once I find out how Jane's promotion class is actually set I'll update this answer. With a bit of luck you or someone else will beat me to it. :)

Comment: I use a variety of mods, including the mods listed by OP. Jane Kelly in my game is a Ranger. However, that may be due to RNG going in favor of Jane.